How to get the label value with the same number of decimals as the ticker symbol
does anyone know if it's possible to control the number of decimal digits based on the ticker symbol, so the label value writes the same umber of decimals? I've pasted a code below where I today use str.tostring in the label.new. I understand that with '#.######' it's possible to control the number of digits. So I wonder if it's possible to control the format string to pass the same number of digits to the value as the no of digits in the specific symbol?
if (newSession)
    prevHightxt := label.new(bar_index+1, h[1], str.tostring(h[1], '#.######') + " (D1 High: " + str.tostring(h[1], '#.######'), style=label.style_none, textcolor= #000000 , size = size.normal, textalign = text.align_right)
    label.delete(id = prevHightxt[1])

I've tried to read through the pinescript manual, searched previous stack overflow discussion.
